# Can I use my iphone 5C as a wireless microphone for my mac (for skype for eg.)?

Tags: iphone, microphone, ios, imac, smartphone

Can I use my smartphone as a microphone ? I tried pocketaudio and other apps but they're all created for live performances.

I have an iMac.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which generation iMac you have but the newer ones all have microphones built in. Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: it's a new generation iMac whith a build-in microphone and only one jack port

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.
You only can use the microphone from the jack connector

Comment: This [article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-your-smartphone-mic-with-your-PC/) suggests that, to a Windows PC at least, it is possible. It should not be that difficult to adapt for OSX.

Comment: @Burgi for that link, they use a cable to connect the phone to the computer. So it doesn't help the OP.

Comment: @Gamerb that was from a 2 second Google, a little more research may provide a wireless method.

Comment: @Burgi you sure. As beforr answering I googled for at least 30min ;)

Comment: i googled for hours guys before i came here. So there's no known solution for that so i thought that maybe there's a little hack for that but unfortunately only an amplification of the sound is available.

Comment: How about this, it is technically possible. I know it is, however, the only way I can think of to get this to work, is to build an iOS app and an OSX app to allow them to communicate with wireless. (Server and Client setup) And I don't think this is the path the OP wants to go down.